# select2 loading array data example not working

Tags: jquery-select2

The loading array data example from the official documenation is just not working for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/Jngai1297/v64rwj7b/7/

html

```
<select class="js-example-data-array-selected">
  <option value="2" selected="selected">duplicate</option>
</select
```

javascript

```
var hidata = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
  data: hidata
})

$(".js-example-data-array-selected").select2({
  data: hidata
})
```

The examples are straight out from the doc and the external resources are correct as well. Been hacking on it half the day and searched around and found nothing.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is missing jQuery, so that's a start. What "isn't working"?

Comment: I add jQuery missing file and it's working now https://jsfiddle.net/3ehrang/z5heaz9m/2/

Comment: You need to add jQuery and newer select2 files now `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   var airPorts = [
    {id:0,text:'airport one'},
    {id:1,text:'airport two'},
    {id:2,text:'airport three'},
    {id:3,text:'airport four'},
  ];

  $('.select2').select2({
    data: airPorts,
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**